# How can I reference a pivot table value from another sheet by the INDIRECT function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-indirect

I use this formula:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sls_LY_GL_Local]",'[2019Innisfil Cube.xlsx]tmp7343'!$A$4,"[Time_Period].[Fiscal Calendar]"
```

Now I try to reference the file name inside the "getpivotdata" function.
I'd like to be able to change 1 cell and have all of my data go to that file instead.

I've tried multiple different formats: With the "!", without, with a "&" between, but I haven't had any luck.
It would be ideal, if H20 cell's value is `[2019Innisfil Cube.xlsx]tmp7343'!`,
and following formula would work, but it doesn't:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Sls_LY_GL_Local]",INDIRECT(H20)$A$4,"[Time_Period].[Fiscal Calendar]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. The value of `H20` is now `'[2019Innisfil Cube.xlsx]tmp7343'!$A$4` and I have put `INDIRECT(H20)` as the reference